PHP Laravel Horizon- How to kill a particular job?
For certain long running jobs that are running under horizon, we have a need to stop them from executing if they are having issues such as performance or contention.
We have tried:
The horizon dashboard (No stop / kill mechanism)
Looking at the output of ps on the supervisor node (no indication of job id)
artisan horizon:clear - (clears all jobs and may not stop running ones)
